# Magento 2 getData() Not showing attribute values

Tags: magento2, product, category

I am trying to get **category_ids**  but below code working for me.
but `print_r($collection->getData());` Not showing attribute values but in **foreach** data is there.

```
foreach ($collection as  $product) {
   print_r($product->getCategoryIds()); // this is working fine 
}
```

my code to get collection

```
   protected $_productCollectionFactory;


   public function __construct( .....
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory,               
                          ....

            .....
            $this->_productCollectionFactory = $productCollectionFactory; 
            ......
    }


    $collection = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()->addAttributeToSelect(array('category_ids'));
```